# Select Property from JArray with Specific Key - VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, json.net

I have an array of screens and field positions on those screens that I'd like to parse.

I've tried using `SelectToken("$.[?('Field-1')])` and am getting an error that multiple tokens are coming back. I've also attempted different flavors of Linq but can't get anything to cooperate.

I'm fairly new to .Net and VB and am kind of struggling. I might even be going about this all wrong and there is a better way to handle it. I'm working in UIPath so I only really have some psuedo-code to show.

Here is some sample JSON. I do have full control over this structure so if there are recommendations for restructuring I'd be happy to entertain them.

```
    [
    {
        "Screen-1": {
            "Field-1": {
                "FieldInfo": {
                    "Row": 16,
                    "Start": 17,
                    "Length": 8,
                    "Validation": [],
                    "Format": {}
                },
                "TitleInfo": {
                    "Row": 16,
                    "Start": 2,
                    "Length": 14,
                    "ExpectedValue": "Field-1"
                }
            },
            "Field-2": {
                "FieldInfo": {
                    "Row": 17,
                    "Start": 17,
                    "Length": 8,
                    "Validation": [],
                    "Format": {}
                },
                "TitleInfo": {
                    "Row": 17,
                    "Start": 2,
                    "Length": 14,
                    "ExpectedValue": "Field-2"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Screen-2": {
            "Field-1": {
                "FieldInfo": {
                    "Row": 2,
                    "Start": 7,
                    "Length": 4,
                    "Validation": [
                        "YES",
                        "NO"
                    ],
                    "Format": {}
                },
                "TitleInfo": {
                    "Row": 2,
                    "Start": 2,
                    "Length": 4,
                    "ExpectedValue": "Field-1"
                }
            },
            "Field-2": {
                "FieldInfo": {
                    "Row": 2,
                    "Start": 16,
                    "Length": 3,
                    "Validation": [],
                    "Format": {}
                },
                "TitleInfo": {
                    "Row": 2,
                    "Start": 12,
                    "Length": 4,
                    "ExpectedValue": "Field-2"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

What I'd like to be able to do is select which screen I want to pull from and then from there index into each field I need and grab specific values. This would need to be consumable from Python, C#, and VB.Net but my primary concern is VB.Net at the moment.

**Goal**:

```
configData = json.Deserialize

screenConfig = configData.Select("Screen-2")

Array ValidationInfo = screenConfig("Field-1")("FieldInfo")("Validation").ToList

-----
List Contents: YES, NO
```

I have considered changing the structure so that we have a specific field for the screen name and then I think I could get selecttoken for it but I don't really see the value in that. It'd look something like this.

```
{
    "Screen": "Screen-1",
    "Data": {
        "Field-1": {
            "FieldInfo": {
                "Row": 16,
                "Start": 17,
                "Length": 8,
                "Validation": [],
                "Format": {}
            },
            "TitleInfo": {
                "Row": 16,
                "Start": 2,
                "Length": 14,
                "ExpectedValue": "Field-1"
            }
        },
        "Field-2": {
            "FieldInfo": {
                "Row": 17,
                "Start": 17,
                "Length": 8,
                "Validation": [],
                "Format": {}
            },
            "TitleInfo": {
                "Row": 17,
                "Start": 2,
                "Length": 14,
                "ExpectedValue": "Field-2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get what I needed using SelectToken. I just was using the JSONPath incorrectly. Below key is the key that I'm interested in so I'm filtering by that and then the `.*` at the end allows me to bring back only what is inside of it.

Solution: `data.SelectToken("$.[?(@."+ key + ")].*")`